# Why RDF store is not included in the types of NoSQL databases

Tags: database, nosql, rdf

After reading some articles about NoSQL databases, I found that there are 4 types of NoSQL databases and for every type there are NoSQL databases.

I understood that NoSQL is Not Only SQL; it means every database that use other query language, but I am confusing why RDF stores are not with this selection of these types (Key/value, Document, Column and Graph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDF stores can be considered as a subclass of graph databases:

1. The central RDF 1.1 notion is [RDF graph](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-rdf-graph).
2. Many triplestores have word 'graph' in their names: [graphdb](/questions/tagged/graphdb), [blazegraph](/questions/tagged/blazegraph), [allegrograph](/questions/tagged/allegrograph)
   (some of them are not only RDF stores though).

Obviously, there are differences between the RDF model and other graph database models.  These differences are described e.g. in [An introduction to Graph Data Management](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00036.pdf) by Renzo Angles and Claudio Gutierrez.

---

See also [Reification is red herring](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2018/04/reification-is-a-red-herring.html) by Bob DuCharme.